# sine wave not going to the amplitude height in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qiluxi/3/edit?html,js,output) of what I have so far.

My sine wave is not going to the y value of 1 or -1, i.e the amplitude.

My yScale is defined like this:

```
const yScaleAxis = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([-1, 1])
        .range([radius, -radius]);
```

And I am creating the values like this:

```
const xValues = [0, 1.57, 3.14, 4.71, 6.28];  // 0 to 2PI

const sineData = xValues.map((x) => {
  console.log(Math.sin(x));
  return {x: x, y: Math.sin(x)};
});
```

The values for y are logged as:

```
0
0.9999996829318346
0.0015926529164868282
-0.999997146387718
-0.0031853017931379904
```

I then use the scale to set the values:

```
const sine = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate('basis')
        .x( (d) => {return xScaleAxis(d.x);})
        .y( (d) => {return yScaleAxis(d.y);});

circleGroup.append('path')
  .datum(sineData)
  .attr('class', 'sine-curve')
  .attr('d', sine);
```

But as you can see in the jsbin the amplitude of the sine wave is not reaching 1 or -1 and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line interpolation method to `monotone`, `basis` corresponds to a [B-spline](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/B-spline)

[More info about the interpolation options provided by d3](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_interpolate)